# Recaptcha not working in flutter with app_release apk

Tags: flutter, recaptcha

I trying captcha for flutter application.It actually as i expected but when i build apk for sharing ,after they installed  onmessagereceived method not calling.

[Used this library](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_recaptcha_v2)

```
  WebView(
initialUrl: "${widget.pluginURL}?api_key=${widget.apiKey}",
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
    JavascriptChannel(
      name: 'RecaptchaFlutterChannel',
      onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage receiver) {
        print(receiver.message);
        String _token = receiver.message;

        if (_token.contains("verify")) {

          print("True");
          _token = _token.substring(7);

        }

         print(_token);
        verifyToken(_token);

      },
    ),
  ].toSet(),
  onWebViewCreated: (_controller) {
    webViewController = _controller;
  },
),
```